# Peer name X.X.X.X is not in peer certificate

Tags: python, go, grpc, grpc-python, grpc-go

It's my first time trying gRPC with [MTLS](https://handwiki.org/wiki/Multiplexed_Transport_Layer_Security), and I ran into some issues.

I have created a service for creating thumbnails in Go, and I want to connect it through gRPC with my Django API (Python). The service is in the *services/thumbnailer/* directory, the API is in *skynotes/* and certificates are in *certs/*. I host everything on Docker and that's what I’m getting:

```
celery.utils.serialization.UnpickleableExceptionWrapper: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
2024-01-10 19:28:46     status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
2024-01-10 19:28:46     details = "failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:172.18.0.2:50051: Peer name thumbnailer is not in peer certificate"
2024-01-10 19:28:46     debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer  {created_time:"2024-01-10T18:28:46.5870333+00:00", grpc_status:14, grpc_message:"failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:172.18.0.2:50051: Peer name thumbnailer is not in peer certificate"}"
```

Here is my code:

Certificates configurations

#### File *cfssl.json*

```json
{
    "signing": {
        "default": {
            "expiry": "87600h"
        },
        "profiles": {
            "rootca": {
                "usages": [
                    "signing",
                    "digital signature",
                    "key encipherment",
                    "cert sign",
                    "crl sign",
                    "server auth",
                    "client auth"
                ],
                "ca_constraint": {
                    "is_ca": true
                },
                "expiry": "87600h"
            },
            "server": {
                "usages": [
                    "signing",
                    "digital signing",
                    "key encipherment",
                    "server auth"
                ],
                "expiry": "87600h"
            },
            "client": {
                "usages": [
                    "signing",
                    "digital signature",
                    "key encipherment",
                    "client auth"
                ],
                "expiry": "87600h"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### File *csr.json*

```json
{
    "hosts": [
        "localhost",
        "127.0.0.1"
    ],
    "key": {
        "algo": "ecdsa",
        "size": 256
    },
    "CN": "localhost",
    "names": []
}
```

#### File *services/thumbnailer/main.go*

```golang
func main() {

    secureAddress := "0.0.0.0:50051"

    tlsConfig, err := LoadTlSConfig("certs/server.pem", "certs/server-key.pem", "certs/root.pem")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    server := grpc.NewServer(
        grpc.Creds(tlsConfig),
        grpc.UnaryInterceptor(MiddlewareHandler),
    )

    api.RegisterThumbnailServiceServer(server, new(api.Server))

    basectx, casncel := signal.NotifyContext(context.Background(), syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
    defer casncel()

    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", secureAddress)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    go func() {
        <-basectx.Done()
        server.GracefulStop()
        log.Println("bye")
    }()

    log.Println("listen and serving...")
    if err := server.Serve(listener); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

#### File *skynotes/services/client.py*

```
import grpc

from thumbnailer import thumbnailer_pb2, thumbnailer_pb2_grpc


class Certs:
    root = None
    cert = None
    key = None

    def __init__(self, root, cert, key):
        self.root = open(root, "rb").read()
        self.cert = open(cert, "rb").read()
        self.key = open(key, "rb").read()


class Client:
    thumbnailer = None

    def __init__(self, addr: str, crt: Certs):
        creds = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials(crt.root, crt.key, crt.cert)
        channel = grpc.secure_channel(addr, creds)
        self.thumbnailer = thumbnailer_pb2_grpc.ThumbnailServiceStub(channel)

    def generate_thumbnail(self, content: bytes) -> bytes:
        return self.thumbnailer.GenerateThumbnail(
            thumbnailer_pb2.ThumbnailRequest(content=content)
        ).thumbnail
```

^ This is the class for connecting to RPC, and the issue seems to be called in the *grpc.ssl_channel_credentials* line.

I tried multiple combinations of using [PEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail) files, but none of these worked.

Comment: drive-by comment: generally certs should be DNS names (e.g. `localhost` in your case) rather than IP addresses. If you've configured the cert correctly, you should be able to use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` but not `0.0.0.0`. Try `secureAddress := "localhost:50051"`

Comment: I use it in docker container so afaik i need to use 0.0.0.0 so it can connect with external world @DazWilkin

Comment: Your code doesn't provide a complete repro. I replicated your code but I'm unable to repro your issue. I also don't have your cert tool and so used my own approach to generate the CA, server and client certs|keys. You're correct about the server port binding (my apologies). It's unclear what address you're using for your client. You may want to consider using a tool like [`gRPCurl`](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl) to validate that a known-working client is able to connect to your containerized server and proceed from there. Good luck!

Comment: Could you provide me some example how should i correctly setup mtls with docker? That actually might be an issue as you said, and i can't find any good example. @DazWilkin

Comment: This [gist](https://gist.github.com/DazWilkin/066970ce13fce597faba33dc6555e8e8) comprises a `config` file used by the script to generate CA, server and client certs and keys. You should be able to run your gRPC server using the CA|server set and your Python client with the CA|client set. You can test using `grpcurl --cacert=./certs/ca.crt --cert=./certs/client.crt --key=./certs/client.key -d '{request}' localhost:50051 {package}.{service}/{Method}`

Comment: Thank you, I've been very busy the last few days, but I'll check it out this week. Just in case I never post on this thread again - Thank you in advance.

Comment: The address `0.0.0.0` only makes sense as a listening address (it means, "listen on all addresses"). You would never use it when initiating a connection, so your earlier comment isn't relevant here. You should be *connecting* to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, or to the hostname/address appropriate for the service container.

Comment: How should i then use it with docker? @larsks